# Open chrome with method Post body data on specific Url

Tags: command-line, google-chrome, batch, post

I want to open Chrome with an url method POST and some data like ValueOne=Value1 and ValueTwo=Value2 and so on...

Is it possible from commandline or batch?

Like 
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" "http://www.url.com" AndHereTheBodyData

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

As far as i know, there's no direct way to do that. But i used a workaround:

TLDR; Use a Data URL containing an auto-submitting form.

[Data URL's](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs) can contain html which the browser will show. So i put a form with the POST data and JS to auto-submit into that URL.
I had to encode the data as base_64.

First, the HTML that will be passed to the browser via the data-url looks like this:

```
<body onload="document.s.submit()">
  <form action="domain.tld/path/script.php" name="s" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="edit"> 
    <input type="submit" value="go">
  </form>
</body>
```

Next, the basic format of the Command and data-url goes like this:

```
start chrome /new-window data:text/html;charset=utf-8;base64,',[base_64_enceded_url] plain-url-in-a-second-tab.tld/path
```

For testing, i used an [online base64 encoder](https://dopiaza.org/tools/datauri/index.php), but for my actual task i created a txt file via MYSQL, from which i cut and pasted a bunch of lines at a time to the Commandline:

```
CONCAT ('start chrome /new-window data:text/html;charset=utf-8;base64,',
 REPLACE(TO_BASE64(CONCAT('<body onload="document.s.submit()"> <form action="somedomain.tld/admin/new_attrib.php" name="s" method="post"><input type="hidden" name="action" value="edit"><input type="submit" value="go"></form></body>')), '\n', ''), ' "anotherurl.tld/somepage.php?products_id=',p.products_id,'&action=edit"  AS PasteMeToWindowsCMD
```

(I added REPLACE() because TO_BASE64() adds newlines. Those would have broken my intent to paste multible commands to CMD at the same time, and would have made cutting commands from a text file to CMD more complicated.)

With this, i got a browser window for each entity (product) i had to edit, with three tabs for three places where i needed to edit.